# What does the sigil .^ mean in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

I would like to know the meaning of the sigil `.^` in Perl 6.

```
put "\"10\" : ", "10".^name; 
say "Type : ", (10.Str).^name;
say $object.^parents;
say $object.^methods;
```

In this code snippet, what does `.^` mean? Is `name` a method or an attribute of the parent class? Or does it have a different meaning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$foo.^bar
```

is effectively syntactic sugar for:

```
$foo.HOW.bar($foo)
```

In other words, call the `bar` method on the meta-class of the `$foo` object (`.HOW`), and pass the object as the first parameter (so that the method knows the instance of the meta-class it should work on).

For instance:

```
say "Hello world".^name                     # Str
say "Hello world".HOW.name("Hello world");  # Str
```

See also: https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-methodop_.%5E

Comment: It's actually `$foo.HOW.bar($foo)`, otherwise it'd be useless if wanting to implement prototype-based OO.

Comment: This looks like the relevant docs page - as the name HOW and ALLCAPS suggest this is getting into the underlying OO mechanisms...    https://docs.perl6.org/type/Metamodel::ClassHOW#(Metamodel::Naming)_method_set_name

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR** An elaboration of Liz's answer plus a bonus section, **The HOW stack**.

```
$foo.^bar
```

The `.^bar` method call is ["Higher order programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_programming), code that works on `$foo` as a programming construct.

> is effectively syntactic sugar

`^` is ["syntax sugar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) because it's short and simple and is a [mnemonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic) for "higher".

```
$foo.HOW.bar($foo)
```

So, rather than `$foo.^bar` calling the `bar` method on the object assigned/bound to `$foo` as usual for method calls, the `bar` method is instead called on the object's **HOW** object (**HOW** is short for **H**igher **O**rder **W**orkings or **H**ow **O**bjects **W**ork).

The conventional wording for a **HOW** object is a ["meta-object"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaobject).

> In other words, call the `bar` method on the *meta-class* of the `$foo` object (`.HOW`)

Afaik the `.HOW` object is normally a concrete *instance*, not a class in the form of a [type object](https://docs.raku.org/language/objects#index-entry-Type_objects). So the `bar` method is normally called on a meta-*object* rather than on a meta-*class*.

Thus, for example, `say 42.HOW` says `Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW.new` with a `.new` on the end, not `(ClassHOW)`. So `42.^bar` would call `.bar` on that meta-*object*.

> and pass the object as the first parameter (so that the method knows the *instance* of the *meta-class* it should work on).

Afaik the object is passed so the method knows the object it must work on and it is very unlikely to be an instance of the meta-class.

For example in:

```
say "String".HOW.name("String"); # Str
```

`"String"` is an instance of the `Str` class, which is `"String"`'s `.WHAT`, not its `.HOW`.

`.WHAT` is an object's type. To force some separation in your mind it may help to think of `.HOW` as more like a type's ["kind"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)).

## The HOW stack

```
class Person { method name { "Fred {rand}" } }

say Person.HOW.HOW.HOW.HOW.HOW.HOW.^name;  # KnowHOW
say Person.HOW.HOW.HOW.^name;              # KnowHOW
say Person.HOW.HOW.^name;                  # NQPClassHOW
say Person.HOW.^name;                      # Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW
say Person.^name;                          # Person
say Person.name;                           # Fred 0.7356364351848212
```

## `KnowHOW`

`Person` followed by 3 or more chained `.HOW`s (and ending with a `.^name`) displays `KnowHOW`.

`KnowHOW` is the "highest" if you will of the **HOW** objects, the one that determines the behavior of generic [6model](https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/master/docs/6model/overview.markdown) objects.

`KnowHOW` is agnostic regarding programming languages and object orientation. It isn't aware of things like classes or interfaces. It just "knows how" to do a few things with one of the most important being that it knows how to get a reference to its meta-object.

And in the unique case of `KnowHOW`, its meta-object is itself. That's why the additional `.HOW` calls after the third are effectively [nops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)).

Given that "the buck stops" with `KnowHOW`, it has to have an "on-the-metal" implementation. This is specific to a given backend such as [the `KnowHOW` code in MoarVM's 6model bootstrap.c code](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/src/6model/bootstrap.c) ([documentation about its creation](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/docs/bootstrap.markdown)).

## `NQPClassHOW`

At the next level, stepping closer to Perl 6, comes [NQP](https://github.com/perl6/nqp), a programming language that was created to write programming languages including itself and Perl 6.

`NQPClassHow` is part of NQP. It's a (meta) object that implements a "class" construct.

NQP isn't as sophisticated as Perl 6. (In fact it's basically a subset of it.) For example, the code `say foo` will always work if `foo` is a standard full P6 object. In contrast, it sometimes won't if `foo` is an NQP object. Hence we have to write the first of these; the second won't work:

```
say Person.HOW.HOW.^name; # NQPClassHOW
say Person.HOW.HOW;       # Died with X::Method::NotFound
```

## `Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW`

Finally we arrive at [a full P6 meta-class](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Metamodel/ClassHOW.nqp), part of [the Rakudo Metamodel](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/docs/metamodel.pod).

It's an instance of this class that's responding to the `name` method call in `say Person.^name`. That response is to display the name of the class of the object passed to it.